# Will using a shorter ccTLD domain versus a longer gTLD affect my web traffic and SEO?

Tags: seo, domains

I have two possible domains to use for a company website which will be partly informational and partly an commerce site. The company is `ETREE UK LTD`.

I can choose between `etr.ee` or `etree.biz`.

The reason I want to move away from `etree.biz` is because we do not own `etree.com`. This means we may lose traffic to that site. I also find `etr.ee` to be convenient and easier to use when directing people to the site.

Would using a `.ee` domain impact my site's SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been in the digital space for many years and worked at a digital marketing agency, and when I would clean up backlink profiles for my clients, `.biz` websites were almost always spammy and never offered any link value to another domain.

That being said, Google may de-value a `.biz` domain in comparison to others (this is just a hunch, because they'll never release their true ranking factors).

Also, it's not recommended to buy a domain that you can't own the `.com` "version."

That being said, using `etr.ee` (and other common TLDs such as `.io` which was a bit trendy) is probably a better bet. Not only is it (arguably) easier for your customers to remember, but there have been an influx of similarly named domains which is new to these search engines. If indeed Google may find the majority of `.biz` domains questionable, `etr.ee` would be neutral ground, if anything.

Comment: Domain name hack aside, the problem with your recommendation is that etr and ee have no semantic value and the OP would lose significant search value over the .biz option. That said, I REALLY APPRECIATE(!!) (did I put enough emphasis in?) your remarks about the .biz TLD. It may be better for the OP to think harder for a worthwhile domain name. We get this a lot. Many people struggle thinking of a domain name and get derailed with pseudo clever stuff along the way. Cheers!!

Comment: The question was edited to better focus on whether to use a _ccTLD_ (Estonia) versus a _gTLD_, so you might want to reformulate your answer based on that.

Answer (score 2):

using .ee will have negative impact only if you

- offer **localized** services or products

AND

- offer them **not** to estonians (people located in Estonia)